# Replace double quotes using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I have the file shown below where each field is separated by a comma. I need to change the 5th field (`"txt4 "(tst)""`) and replace each occurrence of `"` within that field—but excluding the two outer quotes—with `chr(34)`. I.e., the last field should be converted to `"txt4 chr(34)(tst)chr(34)"`. Note that my real data can have many more fields than what is shown here, so it isn't practical to list the specific fields in the solution.

I need to use awk to achieve the output shown below.

sample csv file:

```
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)""
```

desired output:

```
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 chr(34)(tst)chr(34)"
```

Comment: Please (1) format your post properly, using code blocks where appropriate, (2) show the efforts you have made, even if they failed and (3) read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match your question at all. You still have quotes and you have what looks like random new data (`chr(34)(tst)chr(34)`). You say you want to replace quotes with `chr(34)`, so why do you have `chr(34)(tst)chr(34)` in the output _and_ still have quotes? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need.

Comment: "txt4 "(tst)""  - as we have have double quotes before and after (tst) - so the reqmt is to replace each double quote with chr(34)

Comment: I see. And do you absolutely _have_ to use `awk`? It isn't necessarily the best solution here.

Comment: If the internal quotes had been doubled up (`"txt4 ""(tst)"""`) then a CSV parser would have had no issue reading the file as it is. Do you have access to the program that creates this output to correct the printing of the data?

Comment: Repeating what I asked you in that question: Please (1) format your post properly, using code blocks where appropriate, (2) show the efforts you have made, even if they failed and (3) read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: when i tried this cmd it gives error backslash not last character on line awk -F, -vOFS="," '{sub(/^"/,"",$5);sub(/"$/","",$5); sub(/""/,"\"",$5);gsub(/"/,"/"/"",$5);print \"$5\"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's the second of three questions that appear to be fundamentally the same question

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589595/100397

Comment: Your input isn't a valid CSV format by any of the accepted "standards" so, assuming `txt` can contain commas, it's impossible to parse your input reliably. See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really say much about the origin or the expected format of the data.  If the exercise could be reformulated as "replace `"(` by `chr(34)(` and `")` by `)chr(34)`" or "replace `"(tst)"` by `chr(34)(tst)chr(23)`", then the following two `sed` commands would do that:

```
$ sed -e 's/"(/chr(34)(/' -e 's/)"/)chr(34)/' file
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 chr(34)(tst)chr(34)"
```

```
$ sed 's/"\((tst)\)"/chr(34)\1chr(34)/' file
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 chr(34)(tst)chr(34)"
```

Parsing the text as a CSV record is not possible as the formatting of the last field is invalid.  A properly quoted version of the field would have looked like `"txt4 ""(tst)"""`.

Answer (score 0):

Observation here is that a valid CSV field quote is at start of line, end of line, or next to a comma. So: search for each quote plus a character either side. If neither is a comma, double the quote.

This is not infallible: a comma can be inside the quotes in valid CSV, like: "one field,""here". But this works for your data.

Test:

```
Paul--) ./awkFixCsv

"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)"" <<< Input
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 ""(tst)""" <<< Output

"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)"",""","""","done" <<< Input
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 ""(tst)""","""","""""","done" <<< Output

One,Two,"3","Four","Five "and" Six",Seven and Eight,"Nine" <<< Input
One,Two,"3","Four","Five ""and"" Six",Seven and Eight,"Nine" <<< Output
Paul--)
```

Code, with test data as a here document, and the Fix as a function. Comment if you don't know how to incorporate this in your script.

```
#! /bin/bash

AWK='

function Fix (s, Local, t, u, x) {
    while (match (s, ".\042.")) {
        u = substr (s, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        x = (u ~ /..,/ || u ~ /,../) ? 0 : 1;
        t = t substr (s, 1, RSTART + x); 
        s = substr (s, RSTART + 1); 
    }
    return (t s);
}

{ print "\n" $0 " <<< Input"; }
{ $0 = Fix( $0); }
{ print $0 " <<< Output"; }
'
    awk "${AWK}" <<[][]
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)""
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)"",""","""","done"
One,Two,"3","Four","Five "and" Six",Seven and Eight,"Nine"
[][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm#quote_binary) module is quite good at dealing with malformed CSV like this. In particular:

> If there is really bad CSV data, like
>
> ```
> 1,"foo "bar" baz",42 or
>
> 1,""foo bar baz"",42
> ```
>
> there is a way to get this data-line parsed and
>   leave the quotes inside the quoted field as-is. This can be achieved
>   by setting allow_loose_quotes AND making sure that the escape_char is
>   not equal to quote_char.

So for example

```
$ echo '"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)""' | perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new({escape_char => "", allow_loose_quotes => 1, quote_space => 1})} 
  @row = $p->fields() if $p->parse($_); 
  $p->escape_char("\""); $p->print(*STDOUT,\@row);
'
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 ""(tst)"""
```