# doubling quotes using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

Continuation to the earlier question posted - [Replace double quotes using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589553/replace-double-quotes-using-awk)

I have the below sample file each field seperated with comma - need to extract the 5th field which is  "txt4 "(tst)"" and replacing the double quotes by doubling the quotes within that field i.e.
 "txt4 ""(tst)"""

Need to achieve this o/p using awk
When printing the o/p after the transformation - need to print using $0 instead of specifying each field manually (as my original file has more than 40 cols it is not practical to give each field )

sample csv file
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 "(tst)""

desired o/p 
"this is txt1","this is txt2",3,"this txt3","txt4 ""(tst)"""

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589553/100397

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace double quotes using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589553/replace-double-quotes-using-awk)